# ASP.NET webForm variable binding in markup body

Tags: javascript, asp.net, data-binding, webforms

Asp.Net webform 4.5

I am referencing a script with a REV in a master page

```
<script src="<%# "/content/js/master.js?"+ RevID %>"></script>
```

RevID is a Public string in code behind.
This use to be in -head- section, and worked very well with

```
Page.Header.DataBind();
```

I now wish (as recommended) to move all scripts to the end of body.
when done, Page.Header.DataBind(); does not work anymore and I get src="".

```
Page.DataBind();
```

does work BUT it also re bind all control in child pages, so it is not a solution.

so how can I use 
    <%# ... %>
in the body section without 
    Page.DataBind();
?

Comment: In code nuggets,for binding the data with `#`, you have to call `DataBind` method.

Comment: @ Rahul Singh: So it is not possible without Page.databing(), is it ?

Comment: Nope you have to call `DataBind`, try calling DataBind on page and it should work like this:- `Page.DataBind();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comment, if you want to use the code nuggets with `#` you will have to call `DataBind` method. Alternatively, if you have a public string field in code behind like this:-

public string RevID = "3";

Them you can simply access it like this:-

```
<script src="<%= "/content/js/master.js?"+ RevID %>"></script>
```

and this should work fine.